# How do I retrieve a component's props to test in Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to React, Enzyme and Jest and have been thrown in the deep end with testing components I know nothing about.

I need to write a test to check if a prop is defaulting correctly:

```
const columns = cols ? 12 / cols : 4
```

I want to create a test that does something like this:

```
expect(wrapper.find(MyComponent).props.columns).toBe(4)
```

But each time this fails - I cannot get a value for `wrapper.find(MyComponent).props.columns`. The console log returns empty.

I can console log the component, eg:

```
console.log(toJSON(wrapper.find(RevealMoreExperiment)))
```

Which allows me to see the values I need, eg:

```
props: { options: {}, columns: 4, limit: 4, children: [Array] },
```

But I am unsure how to actually retrieve them to use on my .spec.js test file.

Would anyone know how this is done?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2037

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to tell jest that what prop are you going for exactly

```
expect(wrapper.find(MyComponent).prop('name of prop')).toBe(4);
```

Try this