# How to not pass testID to deeper component in Jest and React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Say i have the following custom component:

```
type MyCustomComponentProps = {
   a: string;
   b: number;
   testID?: string; // i want this to be checking these props
}

const MyCustomComponent = (props: MyCustomComponentProps) => {
    
    return // whatever
}
```

When i create the component in my screen i will make it like this:

```
<>
   <>
       <MyCustomComponent a={123} b={'something'} testID='my-test-id'/>
   <>
<>
```

and when testing, it will be

```
    // this fail because can't find the element
    expect(getByTestId('my-test-id').props.a).toBeStrictEqual(123)
```

how to fix this?

Update:
So to make it clearer, i used the render screen that inside have my custom component. Then i want to use the query from the testing library's render to assert my component. like this:

```
it('bla bla bla',()=>{
    const {getByTestId} = render(<MyScreen/>);
    const myComponent = getByTestId('my-test-id');
})
```

Comment: Isn't it data-testid?

Comment: i tried that, but still unable to find. can you try to make some example for me?

Comment: also a question, is the react and react native behave the same way?

Comment: May be this will helpful to you. However this is js not ts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364747/how-to-verify-react-props-in-jest-and-enzyme

Comment: @YJR updated with some more context, unfortunately the one you linked me isn't helpful

Comment: i think you need to put the `data-testid` attribute on an out of the box jsx element. so inside of the `MyCustomComponent` there will be a wrapping div to house all the jsx and you can take that prop and attach it there.